# Let's help askers who are trying to circumvent question block at Stack Overflow

Tags: feature-request, stackoverflow, asking-questions, post-ban, new-users

If a first time asker has an SO account that was recently (say, within a week) [question blocked](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/252645/165773) over there, how about showing them a warning like this:

> **Wait!** You've recently been blocked at Stack Overflow. Consider that quality requirements at Software Engineering are similar. Note that Stack Overflow topics are *not* covered here and that your questions [can't even be migrated to Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/237540/165773) because of the block.

This hopefully would help them avoid further frustration if they get down and close votes, angry comments, blocked migrations and question block over here.

---

Related:

- [Why can't we raise up questions quality?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6990/31260)

  > Per stats, Programmers appear to be [most popular of SE sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/237540/165773) among this category of askers. After being blocked or scared by warnings at Stack Overflow they simply try to dump their low quality stuff over here...
  >
  > SE might want to think about how to improve their UX in order to educate during question composition...
- [How many questions do we get from users recently blocked at SO, how many of these are closed / deleted?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6592/how-many-questions-do-we-get-from-users-recently-blocked-at-so-how-many-of-thes)

  > efforts in SO close vote queue make me think that quite a lot of users started hitting the question ban there... how many questions per day are posted by users that were banned at SO less than a month ago, and how many of these questions end up closed / deleted?

Comment: This would be _very_ useful, but I don't think SE is going to spend any dev time on such a localized issue.

Comment: @YannisRizos I wouldn't be surprised if things turn out that way

Comment: On the other hand, we do have a SE dev that spends copious amounts of time closing crap questions on Programmers. Perhaps Oded will realize that building this for us will save him a lot of time in the long run...

Comment: @YannisRizos feature name [_Oded 24x7 v2.0_](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6795/perform-automatic-checks-for-cross-posting-and-question-block-at-so-when-post-en?lq=1#comment18349_6795 "v1.0 is already taken") :)

Comment: @YannisRizos it may be *somewhat* localized to us, but there are other sites that have people trying to get around a restriction on one by posting to another.  MathOverflow and Math (and Physics?).  There's also likely a ServerFault / SuperUser issue too (though may be less obvious given the size of the sites). Nearly anywhere there is a predefined migration path and question blocks, there is the opportunity for this problem to show up.

Comment: They apparently haven't found [this cheat on Quora](https://www.quora.com/Is-it-common-for-new-programmers-to-be-intimidated-by-Stack-Overflow/answers/7543728).

Comment: @PeterMortensen Tim Post bragged at MSE that new blocks are [designed to make this cheat harder](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/234610/165773 "'it's no longer easier to delete your account and try again...'"). They maybe succeeded but, unfortunately, this didn't cover another easy cheat, to try their luck at Programmers

Comment: @PeterMortensen I'd have to dig, but I recall seeing a question on a meta site about a new user being rate limited after the first post because that ip had too many sub 500 rep users who were rate limited in the past period of time. That would also impact the "just get a new email".

Comment: @MichaelT one MSE post about this is [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/102627/165773): "I just attempted to ask my _first question ever_..."

Comment: Heh... Joel's answer on that Quora is pretty priceless.

Comment: also related: [Why are implementation and debugging questions unwelcome on Programmers.SE?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/7864/31260)

Comment: see also at MSE: [Ways to give users some specific education about question quality and topicality](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/277607/165773)